# MongoDB not adding records

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I've been working very long on trying to straighten this out, but I just can't seem to find where my problem lies. I'm trying to add a record in php into my mongo DB (It is settup already, and I have tested the sample code to make sure it works)

The code for adding a record goes like this:

```
// add a record
$obj = array( "title" => "Calvin and Hobbes", "author" => "Bill Watterson" );
$collection->insert($obj);
```

My code for adding a record:

```
$obj = array($currentarray[0][$currentCol] => $currentarray[$currentRow][$currentCol]);
$collection->insert($obj);
```

If I print_r the object:

```
Array ( [President ] => George Washington ) Array ( [Wikipedia Entry] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington ) Array ( [Took office ] => 30/04/1789 ) Array ( [Left office ] => 4/03/1797 ) Array ( [Party ] => Independent ) Array ( [Portrait] => GeorgeWashington.jpg ) Array ( [Thumbnail] => thmb_GeorgeWashington.jpg ) Array ( [Home State] => Virginia )
```

But, If I search for let's say "Portrait", I get an error:

```
DB Notice: Undefined index: Portrait in /home/me/public_html/yes.php on line 74
```

**Extra code:**

```
// connect
$m = new Mongo();

// select a database
$db = $m->data;

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->test;

do{
while(comparison statement){
$obj = array($currentarray[0][$currentCol] => $currentarray[$currentRow][$currentCol]);
$collection->insert($obj);
}
} while (comparison statement);

// find everything in the collection
$cursor = $collection->find();

// iterate through the results
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo $obj["Party "] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is the record in the database? You can verify that using the MongDB Client named `mongo`

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm very new to php and MongoDB and I have only been able to get by, by looking at the documentation.

Comment: Try running the MongoDB shell: `path/to/mongodb/bin/mongo`
It connects to the server if running on the same machine and listening to port 1527 (I guess).
I your server is not on the same machine or listens to another port you have to use some parameters when starting the shell.

Now if you have a connection you can query the data in the database.
First you have to select a database with the `use`-stmt. And then type `db.mycollection.find()` to get a list of all your entries. Write `help` to get a list of statements more.

Comment: I'm not sure of the path because it is not on my server. Any other ways to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Not without more code. Maybe you can show us the whole code you use related to saving and querying the data.

Comment: And the code of yes.php (where you query the data)?
Besides, does the last `foreach` output some parties?
The code you gave me is mainly taken from the tutorial (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) so I guess there are no errors in there.

Comment: That's all of my code. It includes my query towards the bottom of my question. Here it is: `$cursor = $collection->find();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've figured out my problem (at least for now). My records WERE adding to my database (a quick print_r($obj) on the last problem showed me). So now, my only problems is properly retrieving them, as that's where my errors are coming from.

**Update:**
I was getting errors when I tried to retrieve them because I was trying to "Portrait" in ALL of my arrays. So that's why I was technically getting about 7 errors and 1 actual answer from my retrieve statement.